# how can i get the address of the top of stack with LLVM pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I can get the base of stack with llvm.frameaddress. But how can i get the top of stack for the current function? Such as for X86, i want to get the value of esp. Someone tell me that the TargetLowering can solve it, but it base on the machinefunction, but my pass is base on function(runonfunction). Is there any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: At LLVM IR there is no stack, perhaps you mean MachineInstr or MCInstructions?

Comment: Well,it's my fault. I just want to write some code in pass.

Comment: Then your option is to write the pass at the MachineInstruction level. Secondly you cannot get the address of the base of the stackframe or the top of the stackframe because they are created during runtime. What you can get is a register pointing to it.